# Is there a way to redirect or override an existing ASCX?

Tags: asp.net, ascx

I am working on a ASP.NET site that uses several ascx files scattered throughout the web project, I want to add my ascx files but keep the existing code-behind file. I also want to enable the user to easily switch between the mine and the existing ones. Ideally, I want to enable the user to install the ascx files with minimal hassle without changing any code or going through some complex error-prone process. (The goal is to provide a change of the markup code)

ASP.NET provides ControlAdapters, a mechanism that allows a server control to be customized through adapters that map to a server control. I was wondering if such a mechanism exists for user controls, if not, are there any features or a work-around that provides the same results.

EDIT:

I discovered a "feature" that's not well documented that may allow me to do what I want.  It's called tagMapping.  It is supposed to work with server controls, but it's failed to work with UserControls.

Comment: If you want to exchange it site-wide, why not just edit the existing one?

Comment: I want simplify deployment rather than overwrite an existing file or ask the user to make changes.

Comment: Basically, you're saying "I want to replace (...) but I want to avoid (...) replacing." Elaborate, please.
Just edit the file, after a backup, recompile and deploy?

Comment: I hope my question is clarified.

Comment: I don't see how you could simplify the deployment. You're still going to have to copy your new ASCX to the site, and you're still going to have to change web.config or something to "redirect".

Comment: Correct, but imagine having 100 ascx files that do not reside in a single neat folder. A web.config change would be fine in such a case.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a panel to where you want to display these user controls. Then, load user controls dynamicly how you wish on backend.

```
     UserControl ctrl = (UserControl)this.LoadControl("/UserControls/" 
+ whichone + "/.ascx");
            yourpanel.Controls.Add(ctrl);
```

Comment: Sorry, but the panels already exist and load a predefined user control.  I want to "trick" the page into loading my user control.